# How to control table width in code ignator?

Tags: codeigniter

In codeIgnator frame work the below is my code working properly.But i cannot control the table width. So,when a long value come into the table then table going to extra large width.But i need to wrap the outcomes data.So,How i can fixed the table width? Pls see my code below..

///controller code///

```
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Search_Controller/songSearchPage/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_rbt');
    $config['per_page'] = '5';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     
    //load the model and get results    
    $data[]=array();
    $data['extraHeadContent'] = '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . base_url() . 'js/song_search.js"></script>';   
    $data['results'] = $this->search_model->getSongResult($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));      
    // load the HTML Table Class        
    $this->table->set_heading('Song Name','Album Name','Artist Name');                                                      
    // load the view
    $this->load->view('song_search_page',$data);
```

/////view code/////

```
<div class="song_element_output">
    <?php echo $this->table->generate($results); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>                            
</div>
```

Could anybody can help me to control the table???

Thanks
Riad

Comment: You need to go back to your previous questions and start marking good answers as accepted answers before asking more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.i use a css file to control the table width.

In which div i use the table generator short tag ...table->generate($results); ?>... i use the css on that div.
Let say i use the short tag on  div song_element_output then my css will be:

```
div.song_element_output table
 {
   width:620px;
   font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:10px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid #777;
  }
```

that's it.

Example of my code:

`<div class="song_element_output">
    <?php echo $this->table->generate($results); ?>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

</div>`

Thanks to all
Riad

Answer (score 1):

The table class in codeigniter doesn't support widths and other attributes for the table itself, or for the table cells.

Your options are:
[Extend the native table library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)
or just create your tables the old fashioned way in your view.